# Problem when importing fbx in Unity made in Blender

Tags: unity, blender, fbx, import

First I will explain how do I make my object in Blender:

I want to make an object with a texture that have transparecies (png image). I unwrap my object and then apply the image to it in the UV editor. Then I export my object as fbx.

To try the transparecy first I imported a PNG image as a plane on Blender and adjusted the necessary things in order to make work the transparency. You can appreciate the settings I used in the following image:

[image: Image of the plane with a texture with alpha channel working in Blender]

Until there is all fine. The problem appears when I import the fbx in Unity. The material that I created with the png image is not well visualized.

When I import the fbx object in Unity, this messages appears in the Materials tab:

[image]

What do I have to set here in order to visualize well the image with its alpha channel working?

Furthermore, if I try to change the material settings it is impossible because I cannot click the different options as they are disabled:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I don't know if my error is when creating the material in Blender or when I import the fbx in Unity.

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: Be sure to show us the settings for your material once it's imported into Unity, so we can tell you how to fix them.

Comment: I think you now can see all the settings. Thanks in advantage for your help :)

Comment: You're using an opaque material. Did you mean to use a transparent material instead?

Comment: Do you mean on Blender or in Unity?